# Allow guests to save favourite pages?

Tags: users, cookies, customization

We're creating a site where we want guest users to add pages to a favourites list (post IDs), so they can print or email their selection if they want.

What would the best way be to do this in WordPress? I think ajax but I'm not too sure how to save it in the WordPress framework.

Comment: you can do this with javascript only, and cookies (unless you need to send that email from your site, which is probably not a good idea to do for guests)

Comment: I appreciate this something some sites provide, but isn't it just recreating existing browser functionality? I never saw the point much in that - although that might just be me.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies, or even HTML5 [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html), seem like a good way to implement this. Here's some basic code that could serve as a starting point. Post IDs are stored as CSV in the cookie.

```
// Load current favourite posts from cookie
$favposts = (isset($_COOKIE['favposts'])) ? explode(',', (string) $_COOKIE['favposts']) : array();
$favposts = array_map('absint', $favposts); // Clean cookie input, it's user input!

// Add (or remove) favourite post IDs
$favposts[] = $post->ID;

// Update cookie with new favourite posts
$time_to_live = 3600 * 24 * 30; // 30 days
setcookie('favposts', implode(',', array_unique($favposts)), time() + $time_to_live);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the information directly to a database table, so you'd have a table of userIDs associated with postIDs, and to get the list of posts that user has favorited, you can run a query on the database.

See: [Class Reference/wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)